# Excel help generating product codes

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation, list

Good Day,

I need help generating different product codes for a range of values.

I want the product codes to be:

> SKU0000 to SKU9999

and I also need the subproducts for each of the main products such as:

> SKU0000-a to SKU0000-z
>
> SKU0001-a to SKU0001-z
>
> SKU0002-a to SKU0002-z

ect...

Can anyone advise me how to do this quickly?

Every product code has to be repeated 26 times with each character of the alphabet.

I have tried concatenation and then filling the series down, but the excel file grows in size rather quickly and has a tendency to crash quickly, often and without warning.

These values will be used in a data validation list, but if their is an alternative method to select them from a 'list' and store them, I am all ears.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: crash - how many are there?

Comment: Well, full on it would be 260,000 codes.

Comment: Nevermind, found myself an alternative method that will work much better and faster.

Comment: Please share your solution

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer so others will know the solution. It is acceptable to answer your own question here.

Answer (score 0):

In **A1** enter:

```
="SKU" & TEXT(ROUNDUP(ROW()/26,0)-1,"0000") & "-" & CHAR(96+MOD(ROW()-1,26)+1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: As you still need to automate this answer you could enter your formula in a cell A1, then press F5 (Go To) and enter the range address a1:a260000 then on the home tab click Fill select down and the formula will fill the range.